# RecyclerView items not showing properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, androidx

In my project, I have used `RecyclerView` which is shown in `layout-preview` as I expected but the problem is when I run the `application` in `emulator`/`device` the items of `RecyclerView` not showing as `layout-preview` shown.

**Here is the XML of recyclerview.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".view.LActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/rv_sample" />
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:id="@+id/fabAdd"
        app:tint="@color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**XML of recyclerview items.**

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:strokeColor="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvWord"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:text="@{item.word}"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{item.type}"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvWord" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**Adapter class**

```
class MyAdapter(private var itemList: List<Item>, private val listener: ItemClickListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.VHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = RvSampleBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return VHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = itemList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VHolder, position: Int) = holder.bind(itemList[position])

    inner class VHolder(private val binding: RvSampleBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: Item) {
            binding.item = item
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onItemClick(item)
            }
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
```

> Screenshot of layout-preview

[image: Screenshot of <code>layout-preview</code>]

> And Screenshot of actual output.

[image]

I have run the application in several emulators and devices but can't figure out where is the problem.

Comment: code of adapter, pls

Comment: It's strange because I've copy-pasted your rv_sample layout into my recyclerview implementation and it works just fine. Maybe there's something wrong with the adapter

Comment: Or the way you're initializing it, do post your code for the adapter and other relevant code such as layout manager for recyclerview and how you implemented everything

Comment: Your issue appears to be that your item layout is being inflated without the parent `ViewGroup` passed. It's a common issue, and causes the width to wrap, even though you might have `match_parent` for the `layout_width`. Since the `LayoutInflater` doesn't have the parent, the default `LayoutParams` are generated, and that wraps in both directions. I don't use data binding, but AFAICT, there should have been a `RvSampleBinding.inflate()` overload created that takes 3 parameters: the `LayoutInflater`, the parent `ViewGroup`, and a `boolean`, so `RvSampleBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)`.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM for your helpful comment. Currently, I am in the office, I will try it in my leisure time and let you know.

Comment: Thanks again @MikeM. I have solved my issue based on your comment.

Comment: I have posted an answer based on your comment please see it. if you think the answer needs modification then please tell me or you can modify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here I am going to answer my own question. So that this answer will help other users who will face same issue.

Thanks, **@MikeM** for his helpful comment. All credit goes to him.

**Problem:** The problem is in my adapter, I was inflating the `item-layout` without the parent `viewgroup` passed.

**Cause:** If you don't pass the `parent` in your `layout-inflater` that will `inflate` your `layout` with default `layout-params` and that `wrap` your `content` in both directions(width and height), even though you might have `match_parent` for the `layout_width`.

in my case, I have tried like this

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VHolder {
     val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
     val binding = RvSampleBinding.inflate(inflater) // here i didn't pass viewgroup and boolean parameters.
     return VHolder(binding)
}
```

**Solution:** My problem is solved by modifying the `onCreateViewHolder` like the following.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VHolder {
     val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
     val binding = RvSampleBinding.inflate(inflater,parent,false) //here i have passed viewgroup and boolean parameter and that's solve my problem
     return VHolder(binding)
}
```

Comment: saved my life. could not find a single clue. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So basically your parent Layout is constraint layout, so you have to add all constraint related to all the views, One suggestion just used another parent layout instead of Constraint layout just for the check/validation purpose.

Comment: That's more of a comment, and you have enough reputation to comment

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context=".RecyclerViewActivity"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_ex1">
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_item_ex1" />
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:id="@+id/fabAdd"
            app:tint="@color/cardview_light_background"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

itemview

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:strokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tool:context=".RecyclerViewActivity">
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvWord"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/arrow_right"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="word"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="type"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvWord"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Please vote if it works.

Happy coding. Thanks

[image: final output on device]

Comment: Would you please tell me what is the problem in my design? I think it(my design) should work because in layout-preview it shows as expected.

Comment: I do not see any issue with your xml file. as you can see i have just used your views.
It will be better to understand if you post your binding/adapter sample code.

Comment: The `Adapter` class is already added to my updated question. You can see my updated question.